# Use delete_option in action link

Tags: options

Is it possible to use `delete_option` in an action link directly?

Currently, my thoughts are to add a page named reset.php and link to it. This is not the same as a uninstall. The link would look like the following, and the page would be the simple `delete_option($my_options)`.

```
$settings_links[] = '<a href="' . esc_url( admin_url( 'admin.php?page=reset.php' ) ) . '">Plugin Reset</a>';
```

Is there a plugin doing a reset that someone can suggest I look at that code?

Comment: I think you should use ajax

Comment: Do you know of a plugin doing something similar?

Comment: there is no plugin for option delete

Comment: Thank you. And to clarify, I meant is there a plugin example which uses AJAX to remove their own option that the plugin uses.

Comment: What I suggest is simply learn basic ajax example using wordpress. And at PHP part write code for delete_option